# Laravel array in lang

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to get an array element from Laravel lang files?

For example if i have a following array under resources/lang/en/my.php:

```
<?php

return [
  'fruit' => [1 => 'apple', 2 => 'orange', 3 => 'whatever'],
];
```

and now under my blade view i want to display a fruit a user has chosen:

```
@lang('my.fruits')[2]
```

... but this doesn't work.

How to get the second element of that array in my view?

Comment: It isn't because you have a typo with "fruits" instead of "fruit" Is it?

Comment: The use of numeric indexes in a language file isn't great. If you're translating the content, how do you know what `my.fruit.2` is? `my.fruit.apple` would be far more intuitive.

Answer (score 4):

Try `@lang("my.fruit.1")`. `@lang` uses the dot notation so even numeric indexes should work.

Answer (score 0):

__('my.fruit.2');
$orange = trans('my.fruit.2');